# How to use search in icarousel current index item?

Tags: swift, search, reloaddata, icarousel

Hey all I am just wondering how can I use a search bar to reload data in carousel item without reloading all other items?

below is the code for the carousel:

to Note the concerned one is `if == "Languages"`

```
lazy var car:iCarousel = {
        let view = iCarousel()
        view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:Int(CGFloat(Double(Int(Float(bounds.size.height*0.05))) + globW  )) , width: Int(Float(bounds.size.width)*0.85), height: Int(Float(bounds.size.height)*0.75))
//        view.type = .coverFlow
        view.type = .wheel
        view.isVertical = true
        view.bounces = true
        view.decelerationRate = 0.0
        view.clipsToBounds=true
//        view.isScrollEnabled = false
//        view.backgroundColor = .red

        return view
    }()
```

below is the concerned case for the carousel item:

```
case "C":
                
                let titleV:UILabel!
                let titleOption:NSMutableAttributedString!
                let fSAttr = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: bounds.size.width*0.04)!,
                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                ]

                titleOption = NSMutableAttributedString(string:currentField[index].placeholder!, attributes: fSAttr)
                let widthFS = titleOption.width(containerHeight: v.bounds.width*0.5)
        
                img.frame=CGRect(x: Double(v.bounds.width)*0.5-Double(bounds.size.width)*0.05, y: Double(v.bounds.height)*0.2, width:Double(bounds.size.width)*0.1, height: Double(bounds.size.width)*0.1)
           
                img.image=UIImage(named: currentField[index].path!)?.resized(to: CGSize(width: CGFloat(bounds.size.width*0.1), height: CGFloat(bounds.size.width*0.1)))
                v.addSubview(img)
                
                titleV = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:Int((v.bounds.width - widthFS)*0.5)  , y: Int(-v.bounds.height*0.02), width: Int(Float(0.449*bounds.size.height)), height: Int(Float(0.567*bounds.size.height))))
                titleV.backgroundColor = .clear
                titleV.attributedText = titleOption
//                v.bounds.height*0.33
//                titleV.isEditable = false
                v.addSubview(titleV)
                currentCarView = v
                if currentField[index].id == "Languages"{
                    let cont=UITextField()
                    //  TRY TO RELOAD V AND VIEW
                    // find children and an id
                    
          
//                        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMr8fg5LZcU
                    
//                    https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started
                   
                    cont.tag = index
//                    cont.text = topkol
//                    cont.becomeFirstResponder()
                    cont.textColor = .white
                    cont.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray])
                    cont.setBottomBorder(color:UIColor.gray.cgColor)
                    cont.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(Int(Float(car.bounds.width*0.4))), y: v.bounds.height*0.5 /*CGFloat(Int(Float(car.frame.height*0.5)))-25*/, width:CGFloat(Int(Float(car.bounds.width*0.6))), height: 50)
                    cont.backgroundColor = .clear
                    cont.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editSearch(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
                    cont.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editSearch(_:)), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
                    v.addSubview(cont)
                }
                for n in 0..<currentField[index].selections!.count{
                    let buttonVal = UIButton()
                    buttonVal.tag = index
                    buttonVal.accessibilityIdentifier = currentField[index].selections![n]
              
                    if currentField[index].id == "Languages"{
                    
                        
                        //replace with search array currentField[index].selections![n]
                        let languageComponent: [String] = currentField[index].selections![n].components(separatedBy: "-");
                           let lastElement = languageComponent[languageComponent.count - 1];
//                            let elem = languageComponent

//
                        let b = (n)/4
                        let x = 0.2 +  Double(Int(Double((n))-floor(Double(b))*4))*0.2
                        let y = 0.1*floor(Double(b)) //0.05 0.55 0.1
                        
//                        Double(v.bounds.height)*y
                        buttonVal.frame=CGRect(x: Double(v.bounds.width)*Double(round(x*10)/10)-12.5, y:  Double(v.bounds.height)*y, width:Double(v.bounds.width)*0.11, height: Double(v.bounds.width)*0.11)
                        buttonVal.setTitle(countryFlag(country: lastElement), for: .normal)
                      
                        Scroll.contentSize.height = CGFloat(Double(v.bounds.height)*y)+CGFloat(Double(v.bounds.height)*0.1)
                        Container.frame.size = CGSize(width: car.bounds.width, height: Scroll.contentSize.height)
                        Container.addSubview(buttonVal)
                        Scroll.addSubview(Container)
                        if !Scroll.isDescendant(of: v){
                            v.addSubview(Scroll)
                        }
                      
//                        v.backgroundColor = .green
                       
//                        print(countryName(countryCode: "DE")!)
          
                    } else {
                        let x = n == 0 ? 0.2 : n == 1 ? 0.5 : 0.8
    //                    print("the W",v.bounds.width)
                        buttonVal.frame=CGRect(x: Double(v.bounds.width)*Double(x)-12.5, y: Double(v.bounds.height)*0.6, width:Double(v.bounds.width)*0.11, height: Double(v.bounds.width)*0.11)
                        
                        let imageVal = UIImage(named: currentField[index].selections![n])?.resized(to: CGSize(width: CGFloat(bounds.size.width*0.1), height: CGFloat(bounds.size.width*0.1)))

                    buttonVal.setImage(imageVal!.resized(to: CGSize(width: v.bounds.width*0.075, height: v.bounds.width*0.075)), for: .normal)
                        v.addSubview(buttonVal)
                    }

                    buttonVal.layer.cornerRadius = v.bounds.width*0.055
                  
                    if currentField[index].id == "Gender" {
                        if currentField[index].text == currentField[index].selections![n]{
                            //HERE
                            buttonVal.backgroundColor = .white
                        }
                    selArr.append(selButtons(name:buttonVal, tag:index))
                    } else {
                        for r in 0..<currentField[index].selected!.count{
                            if currentField[index].selections![n] == currentField[index].selected![r] {
                            buttonVal.backgroundColor = .white
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
             
                    buttonVal.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editTypeC(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
                }
```

Here is the editfunction:

```
@objc func editSearch(_ sender:UITextField){
      
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            sender.text = sender.text!
            
            currentCarView.backgroundColor = .red
     car.reloadData()
            car.currentItemView?.reloadInputViews()
        }
 
  
    }
```

thank you all for your item, please. do suggest for better ways